# How to check which checkboxes are checked in PyQt5

Tags: python, api, user-interface, checkbox, pyqt5

I'm trying to create a simple desktop app that gets an IP address and show it's location using a REST API (including country, city, isp, regionName and timezone). I have 5 checkboxes in my form so that the user can decide what data will be shown (city, country, isp etc).

The way i did it was by using 5 If statements for each checkbox which don't seem a good way of doing it. 
Also in order to set the returned values from API to the lineEdits, again i had to use 5 if statements for each lineEdit.

Is there any other way of checking which checkboxes are checked so that i can call the API with the data related to those checkboxes?
My snippet:

```
def set_params(self,IP):
        try:
            socket.inet_aton("%s" %IP)
        except:
            pass #for now

        else:


            if self.ui.checkBox_City.isChecked():

                city = "city"
            else:
                city = None

            if self.ui.checkBox_Country.isChecked():
                country = "country"
            else:
                country = None

            if self.ui.checkBox_Rname.isChecked():
                Rname = "regionName"
            else:
                Rname = None

            if self.ui.checkBox_ISP.isChecked():
                ISP = "isp"
            else:
                ISP = None

            if self.ui.checkBox_Time.isChecked():  
                time = "timezone"
            else:
                time = None 


            param = {"fields": "{},{},{},{},{}".format(country,city,ISP,Rname,time)}             


            r = requests.get("http://ip-api.com/json/{}".format(IP), params=param)

            resdict = r.json()
            #print(resdict)


            if "country" in resdict.keys():
                self.ui.lineEdit_Country.setText(resdict["country"])

            if "city" in resdict.keys():
                self.ui.lineEdit_City.setText(resdict["city"])

            if "isp" in resdict.keys():
                self.ui.lineEdit_ISP.setText(resdict["isp"])

            if "timezone" in resdict.keys():
                self.ui.lineEdit_Time.setText(resdict["timezone"])

            if "regionName" in resdict.keys():
                self.ui.lineEdit_Country.setText(resdict["regionName"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the check boxes and the line edits in a dictionaries using "city", "country", etc. as keys and use these in `set_params` to check the state of the check boxes and set the text of the line edits. So, after you setup the ui (presumably somewhere in `__init__`) you would set

```
self.check_boxes = {'country':self.ui.checkbox_Country, 'city':self.ui.checkbox_City, 
                    'isp':self.ui.checkbox_ISP, 'regionName':self.ui.checkbox_Rname, 
                    'timezone':self.ui.checkbox_Time}
self.line_edits = {'country':self.ui.lineEdit_Country, 'city':self.ui.lineEdit_City, 
                   'isp':self.ui.lineEdit_ISP, 'regionName':self.ui.lineEdit_Rname, 
                   'timezone':self.ui.lineEdit_Time}
```

In `set_params(self,IP)` you could then use these dicts according to

```
def set_params(self.IP):
    try:
        ....
    except:
        ....
    else:
        # iterate over dict with check boxes to check their state
        values = [key for key, check_box in self.check_boxes.items() if check_box.isChecked()]
        param = {"fields": ','.join(values)}

        r = requests.get("http://ip-api.com/json/{}".format(IP), params=param)

        resdict = r.json()

        # iterate over dict with line edits and set the text of the line edit if the corresponding key is in resdict.
        for key, line_edit in self.line_edits.items():
            line_edit.clear()
            if key in resdict.keys():
                line_edit.setText(resdict[key])
```

Comment: I've updated my code, but it's hard to test if it works correctly without a minimal working example.

Comment: I tested the previous one and it did work. Why did you use a List instead of the previous dictionary for `values`?

Comment: I changed the dictionay to a list because I figured that since the None values are irrelevant thay could as well be omitted. Also, without the None values, you can just use `str.join` to create the value for the "fields" parameter instead of a formatted string.